# PHP readfile returning NULL

Tags: php, http-headers

Can anyone please help readfile returning null. As per the docs it should return false on error, why is it giving null as response.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

The file exists at path and also the permissions are set. The http response for the page is 200 OK.

```
$fileout = "/path/to/image/image.jpg";    
if( file_exists( $fileout ) ) {

/* We already have a resized image
  * So send the file to the browser */
    switch(strtolower($ext))
        {
            case ".gif":
                header ("Content-type: image/gif");
                readfile($fileout);
                break;
            case ".jpg":
                header ("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
                readfile($fileout);
                break;
            case ".png":
                header ("Content-type: image/png");
                readfile($fileout);
                break;
        }
}
```

The same code on a different server (localhost) is working fine, please suggest where shuld I hit to get this issue fixed.

Comment: If you dump `fopen($fileout)`, do you get an error or a file pointer? Is error reporting enabled (E_ALL or -1)?

Comment: The folder permissions are already set, I have even tried 777, but still the same issue

Comment: File permissions need to be set too, but that's not what I asked.

Comment: fopen does not give any error. var_dump(fopen($fileout,'r')); => resource(7) of type (stream). Can readfile can be blocked in php.ini?

Comment: when I use echo file_get_content($fileout), the images are showing up. Can anyone please explain why readfile not working where as fopen/file_get_content are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the issue  readfile function was disabled in server (php.ini). There is php settings in php.ini "disable_functions" where we can specify the list of functions that need to disabled. In my case readfile was listed in this, when I removed it seems working.

PHP has a lot of functions which can be used to crack your server if not used properly. You can set list of functions in php.ini using disable_functions directive. This directive allows you to disable certain functions for security reasons. It takes on a comma-delimited list of function names.

See http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions for more details